# Is there another ending to Don't Look Back?

Tags: dont-look-back

After I picked up the ghost girl, I reach to myself (apparently) and the game ends (I think).
I wanted to know if there is another ending to this game or is that all there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No additional endings; that's all there is.